# Porting C endianness & pointers black magic to Swift

Tags: c, swift, pointers, endianness

I'm trying to translate this snippet :

```
ntohs(*(UInt16*)VALUE) / 4.0
```

and some other ones, looking alike, from C to Swift.
Problem is, I have very few knowledge of Swift and I just can't understand what this snippet does... Here's all I know :

- `ntohs` swap endianness to host endianness
- `VALUE` is a `char[32]`
- I just discovered that Swift : `(UInt(data.0) << 6) + (UInt(data.1) >> 2)` does the same thing. Could one please explain ?
- I'm willing to return a Swift `Uint` (`UInt64`)

Thanks !

Comment: Casting a `char` pointer (or array) to `UInt16*` is rather unsafe, and it can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: That's no pointer black magic. It's just a reinterpreting cast. You should see some real pointer magic...

Comment: @cmaster It's undefined behavior, so it's not the good kind of magic ;-)

Comment: @zwol I agree that it's not written in the best way possible. However, it's only undefined behavior if you can't guarantee alignment of the `char` buffer that's used. If that buffer is allocate with `malloc()`, it's sufficiently aligned and no UB is caused. Things are different if the buffer is on the stack, though: the compiler is not required to align the `char` array in any way, which can indeed lead to UB of the worst kind in theory. In practice, that UB likely won't manifest: there's an excellent chance that the buffer ends up aligned, and most CPUs can handle misaligned reads of 16 bits.

Comment: @cmaster It is undefined behavior per the type-based aliasing rules, regardless of where `VALUE` is allocated or how it is aligned.  The only way it would not be UB is if `VALUE` itself had been converted *from* a pointer to (array-of-)`UInt16` earlier, and the data pointed to had not been modified in between the two conversions.  But if that were the case there would have been no need to call `ntohs`.

Comment: @zwol There is an explicit exception in the strict aliasing rules for casts to/from `char` types. Otherwise `memmove()` and friends would be impossible to implement in a standard compliant way.

Comment: @cmaster Yes, but it's **asymmetric**.  You can access any object via a pointer-to-`char`, but you can **not** access an array of `char` via a pointer to some other type.

Comment: @zwol Ah, yes, you are right, that slight asymmetry escaped my notice. Mainly because the definition of a memory object is purely a language construct. Of course, that asymmetry allows the standard to dodgo the alignment issue. But it leaves the question of how `calloc()` is supposed to work according to the standard: `calloc()` has to treat the memory object that it returns as a `char` array, which is then reinterpreted via a `void*` to some other memory object. According to the asymmetric strict aliasing rules `if(*(int*)calloc(sizeof(int))) ...` seems to be undefined behavior...

Comment: @cmaster It isn't, but you have to read the "effective type" rules (C99 §6.5p6,7) very carefully to understand why it isn't. The object pointed-to by the value returned from `calloc` is an "object having no declared type" which has *not* been "stored into ... through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type", so the "effective type" of your `int` read is in fact `int` and you're OK.

Comment: @cmaster ... Hmm, actually it is starting to sound like `unsigned char *foo = calloc(sizeof(int)); foo[0] = 0xAA; int val = *(int *)foo;` *does* have well-defined behavior -- but if that had been `static unsigned char foo[sizeof(int)]` instead it wouldn't be.  Oh my aching head.

Comment: @cmaster I've hoisted this tangent to its own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967447/ub-on-reading-object-using-non-character-type-when-last-written-using-character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `VALUE` is a pointer to 32 bytes (`char[32]`).
2. The pointer is cast to `UInt16` pointer. That means the first two bytes of `VALUE` are being interpreted as `UInt16` (2 bytes).
3. `*` will dereference the pointer. We get the two bytes of `VALUE` as a 16-bit number. However it has net endianness (net byte order), so we cannot make integer operations on it.
4. We now swap the endianness to host, we get a normal integer.
5. We divide the integer by `4.0`.

To do the same in Swift, let's just compose the byte values to an integer.

```
let host = (UInt(data.0) << 8) | UInt(data.1)
```

Note that to divide by `4.0` you will have to convert the integer to `Float`.

Comment: EDIT : We were writing at the same time. Your solution looks nicer and safer than mine (using UnsafePointer), so I'll gladly take yours. thanks also for the nice explanations !

Comment: Not a pointer to 32 bytes. Pointer to an area where a Uint16 is expected to be found. That is an unsigned int on 16 bits (2 bytes) in network order. Its value is divided by 4.0.

Comment: If `data.0` contains the MSB and `data.1` the LSB of a 16-bit integer, then `(UInt(data.0) << 8) | UInt(data.1)` already is the correct number and must *not* be byte-order converted.

Comment: @MartinR You are absolutely right. I had to be tired.

Answer (score 2):

The C you quote is technically incorrect, although it will be compiled as intended by most production C compilers.¹  A better way to achieve the same effect, which should also be easier to translate to Swift, is

```
unsigned int val = ((((unsigned int)VALUE[0]) << 8) |  // ² ³
                    (((unsigned int)VALUE[1]) << 0));  // ⁴

double scaledval = ((double)val) / 4.0;                // ⁵
```

The first statement reads the first two bytes of `VALUE`, interprets them as a 16-bit unsigned number in network byte order, and converts them to host byte order (whether or not those byte orders are different).  The second statement converts the number to `double` and scales it.

¹ Specifically, `*(UInt16*)VALUE` provokes undefined behavior because it violates the type-based aliasing rules, which are **asymmetric**: a pointer with character type may be used to access an object with any type, but a pointer with any other type may **not** be used to access an object with (array-of-)character type.

² In C, a cast to `unsigned int` here is necessary in order to make the subsequent shifting and or-ing happen in an unsigned type.  If you cast to `uint16_t`, which might seem more appropriate, the "usual arithmetic conversions" would then convert it to `int`, which is signed, before doing the left shift.  This would provoke undefined behavior on a system where `int` was only 16 bits wide (you're not allowed to shift into the sign bit).  Swift almost certainly has *completely different* rules for arithmetic on types with small ranges; you'll probably need to cast to *something* before the shift, but I cannot tell you what.

³ I have over-parenthesized this expression so that the order of operations will be clear even if you aren't terribly familiar with C.

⁴ Left shifting by zero bits has no effect; it is only included for parallel structure.

⁵ An explicit conversion to `double` before the division operation is not necessary in C, but it is in Swift, so I have written it that way here.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the code is taking the single byte value[0]. This is then dereferenced, this should retrieve a number from a low memory address, 1 to 127 (possibly 255).
What ever number is there is then divided by 4.

I genuinely can't believe my interpretation is correct and can't check that cos I have no laptop. I really think there maybe a typo in your code as it is not a good thing to do. Portable, reusable

I must stress that the string is not converted to a number. Which is then used

Comment: `UInt16` are 2 bytes, not 1 byte. There is no string.

Comment: @Sulthan is right. Moreover... there is definitely *no* typo. It's production code, battle-tested and used by many, many open source projects, and probably some other paid ones too ;-)