# memcpy from one type to another type. How do we access the destination afterwards?

Tags: c++11, strict-aliasing

```
uint32_t u32 = 0;
uint16_t u16[2];
static_assert(sizeof(u32) == sizeof(u16), "");
memcpy(u16, &u32, sizeof(u32)); // defined?
// if defined, how to we access the data from here on?
```

Is this defined behaviour? And, if so, what type of pointer may we use to access the target data after the `memcpy`?

Must we use `uint16_t*`, because that suitable for the *declared* type of `u16`?

Or must we use `uint32_t*`, because the type of the source data (the source data copied from by `memcpy`) is `uint_32`?

(Personally interested in C++11/C++14. But a discussion of related languages like C would be interesting also.)

Comment: It does now :-) (I had forgotten an `&`, and another typo)

Comment: Are you trying to find out the endianness of your CPU?

Comment: @Bob__, I have no particular application in mind at the moment. But I will say that, depending on the answer, it might allow some aggressive optimizations I might consider in future in certain projects.

Comment: @Bob__, maybe this better communicates what I am hoping to confirm: "*Given a variable declared to have type `X`, it will **always** be legal to access it via a pointer of type `X`. And `memcpy` into such a variable is always cool and won't change the type, as long as you stick to simple types where you can reason about the bit patterns (integers, pointers, ...) and don't have a problem with trap representations or alignment"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard delegates to C standard:

> The contents and meaning of the header `<cstring>` are the same as the C standard library header `<string.h>`.

The C standard specifies:

> 7.24.1/3 For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

So, to answer your question: Yes, the behaviour is defined.

Yes, `uint16_t*` is appropriate because `uint16_t` is the type of the object.

---

No, the type of the source doesn't matter.

C++ standard doesn't specify such thing as object without declared type or how it would behave. I interpret that to mean that the effective type is implementation defined for objects with no declared type.

Even in C, the source doesn't matter in this case. A more complete version of quote from C standard (draft, N1570) that you are concerned about, emphasis mine:

> 6.5/6 [...] If a value is copied **into an object having no declared type** using memcpy or memmove, or is copied as an array of character type, then the effective type of the modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the value is the effective type of the object from which the value is copied, if it has one. [...]

This rule doesn't apply, because objects in `u16` do have a declared type

Comment: A small follow up: the 'declared type' of an object, if it has one, can never change? And an object can never lose or gain a 'declared type'? But the 'effective type' can change in certain circumstances?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid declared type doesn't change. If object has declared type, then it is the effective type as well - and it doesn't change. Effective type can be gained or changed, if there is no declared type.

Comment: I now think that a huge proportion of the strict-aliasing answers on other questions on Stack Overflow would make a lot more sense if these comments here about 'declared' and 'effective' type were prefaced to the start of every answer.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I know of no definitions for "declared type" and "object" which will be consistent with all existing compiler behaviors.  If a function receives a pointer of type `foo*`, compilers may treat its target as though it has a declared type of `foo`, regardless of whether it actually does or not.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this defined behavio[u]r?

Yes. `memcpy`ing into a pod is well-defined and you ensured that the sizing is the correct.

> Must we use `uint16_t*`, because that suitable for the declared type of `u16`?

Yes, of course. `u16` is an array of two `uint16_t`s so it must be accessed as such. Accessing it via a `uint32_t*` would be undefined behavior by the strict-aliasing rule.

It doesn't matter what the source type was. What matters is that you have an object of type `uint16_t[2]`.

---

On the other hand, *this*:

```
uint32_t p;
new (&p) uint16_t(42);
std::cout << p;
```

is undefined behavior, because now there is an object of a different type whose lifetime has begin at `&p` and we're accessing it through the wrong type.

Comment: One thing that worries me is that there are sentences in the C standard that suggest to me that the type is `uint32_t`, for example "[the type becomes ] ... the effective type of the object from which the value is copied ... ". I don't have any standards documents to hand, all I can do is copy and paste stuff that I find online - I found that sentence here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970251/what-is-the-effective-type-of-an-object-written-by-memset

Comment: @AaronMcDaid C++ is not C.

Comment: Except when C++ explicitly states that it *is* C, in some contexts. (See the answer from user2079303).

Comment: Has this any advantage over a `reinterpret_cast`? Both should lead to implementation defined results, I think.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm just going to repeat that C++ isn't C. `memcpy` doesn't begin the lifetime of an object, only acquiring storage and (where necessary) calling a constructor does. Your `uint16_t` array contains two `uint16_t`s. There is no object of type `uint32_t` there.

Comment: @Bob__ `reinterpret_cast` is UB.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I should clarify that 6.5/6 from C standard that you and I quote do not apply to C++. 7.24 and few other chapters explicitly stated do  apply to C++.