# Copying integer to char buffer in C

Tags: c

```
  uint32_t after = 0xe1ca95ee;
  char new_buf[4];
  memcpy(new_buf, &after, 4);
  printf("%x\n", *new_buf); // I want to print the content of new_buf
```

I want to copy the content of `after` to `new_buf`. But the result is confusing. `printf` gives me `ffffffee`. It looks like an address. I have already dereferenced `new_buf`.

According to the comments, I can't use `memcpy` or `strncpy` to do this task. But why? `memcpy` and `strncpy` are only designed to handle `char *`? But the content of `after` is in memory.

PS: I know I should use `sprintf` or `snprintf`. If you can explain why `memcpy` and `strncpy` is not for this case, I appreciate it.

Comment: are you sure you want to do `memcpy()`?

Comment: why not http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm

Comment: What exactly did you expect to be printed?  There are several different things you could have been trying to accomplish and I can't tell which.

Comment: Until the larger issues of why code needs to "copying integer to char buffer", the answers will still be coming up short.  Copy `uint32_t after` to a `uint8_t new_buf8[4];` makes some sense, but to a `char []` hints to the beginning of a larger coding goal that is problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem right here:

```
printf("%x\n", *new_buf);
```

This gives you what you asked for: it prints the *char* at location **new_buf** using %x format. that location contains 0xee already (after your successful memcpy, least significant byte first, since you're most probably on an Intel machine, little endian), but it is printed as 0xffffffee (a negative number), since it's a *char* and not an *unsigned char*, and because ofcourse 0xee is a signed byte (> 0x7F, highest bit set)

You should use instead:

```
printf("%x\n", *((unsigned int*)new_buf));
```

...edited below...

Or rather:

```
printf("%x\n", *((uint32_t*)new_buf));
```

Comment: Also, be aware of endianess.

Comment: Both of your suggested constructs have undefined behavior due to the asymmetry of the pointer-aliasing rules.  (You can access an object of any type via a pointer with character type, but you can **not** access an object declared to have character type via a pointer with non-character type.)

Comment: @zwol but we're not accessing an object of character type. We're accessing an object of `char[4]` type.

Comment: @PSkocik "Character type" is a term-of-art in the C standard which encompasses both single `char` objects and arrays of them (and probably some other stuff I don't remember off the top of my head).  Regardless, the point is that `char[4]` and `int` are not compatible types and therefore you cannot use `int*` to access memory declared as `char[4]`, *even though* you *can* use `char*` to access memory declared as `int`. There is a special exception for `char*` but it only goes in one direction.

Comment: @zwol Of course it's undefined. It's undefined because it depends on the bit representation of ints (i.e., big endian, little endian,...). But do you have a pointer of type http which explains why it should be undefined any more than that?

Comment: @zwol Any way, if you're talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing, at no point are we storing fundamentally different pointers to the same chunk of data so I don't see how that would apply here.

Comment: @PSkocik Dependence on the bit representation of an integer is usually only enough to make something unspecified or implementation-defined.  (For instance, given `union { int x; unsigned char c[sizeof(int)]; } u; u.x = 0x12345678;` the values of `u.c[0]` through `u.c[sizeof(int)]` are *unspecified.*) (cont'd...)

Comment: @PSkocik http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf is the closest approximation to the text of ISO C2011 that is publicly available online for free.  The relevant text is on physical page 95 of that document (section 6.5, paragraphs 6 and 7).  You don't need *two different pointers* to the same chunk of data to make something undefined by type-based aliasing violation; you only need a chunk of data with a declared type, plus a pointer to that address with an incompatible type.

Comment: @PSkocik See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967447/ub-on-reading-object-using-non-character-type-when-last-written-using-character for a great deal more discussion.

Comment: @zwol OK, I see how that makes sense. Thanks for that info.

Answer (score 3):

If you do this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("%x\n", new_buf[i]);
```

You can see it prints

```
ffffffee
ffffff95
ffffffca
ffffffe1
```

So your bytes are all there. As pointed out by @George André, they are signed bytes, so you see `f`s being padded to the front because the numbers are negative and it always prints 4 bytes, `ee` represented in 32 bits is `ffffffee`. You are probably on a little-endian machine so that the least significant byte `ee` is actually stored at the lowest memory position, which is why you get the "last" byte of your number when dereferencing `new_buf`. The other part is answered already by others, you must declare `new_buf` as unsigned or cast during printing.

```
   uint32_t after = 0xe1ca95ee;
   char new_buf[4];
   memcpy(new_buf, &after, 4);
   printf("%x\n", *((unsigned char*)new_buf));
```

Or alternatively

```
   uint32_t after = 0xe1ca95ee;
   unsinged char new_buf[4];
   memcpy(new_buf, &after, 4);
   printf("%x\n", *new_buf);
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, he wants to print out the uint32_t at new_buf location. Also the "ones" come from the fact that new_buf is signed char, and printf treats those as.. well.. signed chars/integers. all of his bytes are higher than >0x80, so they are inherently signed.

Also *((unsigned char*)new_buf) won't help him at all, he will get the first character, unsigned, only.

Comment: @GeorgeAndré Well yes. You are right insofar as the OP probably wants to print the whole thing (at least I read that from the one comment), this should simply demonstrate how to access the elements of `new_buf` so the results will make sense, correcting the errors above. Printing the first byte was my intention, so it *does* help. Your point about the byte values is right though, I totally missed it. I'll edit that out.

Answer (score 0):

### If you're trying to copy an integer and print it to stdout, as an integer, in base 16:

```
char new_buf[4];
...
printf("%x\n", *new_buf);
```

Whatever you stored in `new_buf`, it's *type* is still `char[4]`. So, the *type* of `*new_buf` is `char` (it's identical to `new_buf[0]`).

So, you're getting the first *char* of your integer (which may be the high or low byte, depending on platform), having it automatically promoted to an integer, and then printing that as an unsigned int in base 16.

`memcpy` has indeed copied your value into the array, but if you want to print it, use

```
printf("%x\n", *(uint32_t *)new_buf);
```

or

```
printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x\n", new_buf[0], new_buf[1], new_buf[2], new_buf[3]);
```

(but note in the latter case your byte order may be reversed, depending on platform).

---

### If you're trying to create a char array containing a base-16 string representation of your number:

Don't use `memcpy`, that doesn't convert from the integer to its string representation.

Try

```
uint32_t after = 0xe1ca95ee;
char new_buf[1 + 2*sizeof(after)];
snprintf(new_buf, sizeof(new_buf), "%x", after);
printf("original %x formatted as '%s'\n", after, new_buf);
```

(the buffer is sized to give 2 chars per octet, plus one for the nul-terminator).

Comment: `*(uint32_t *)new_buf` triggers undefined behavior.  The pointer-aliasing rules are asymmetric: you can access an object of any type via a pointer with character type, but you can **not** access an object declared to have character type via a pointer with non-character type.

Comment: @zwol, can one read and write 32-bit integers from and to a `char` buffer through a pointer to `union { char c[sizeof(uint32_t)]; uint32_t i32; }`?

Comment: @Ant_222 Not through a pointer to `uint32_t`; only by literally accessing the `i32` field of that union.  And, infuriatingly, not in C++ at all (a crucial adjustment to the rules for unions in a corrigiendum for C99 has never been picked up by the C++ standard).